# fighting with user agent stylesheet css

Tags: css, google-chrome, stylesheet, user-agent

I have problem with spacing between images.
I've tried everything but in firefox / opera work perfect, but chrome and IE add space between pictures.

So I even removed all the CSS, that doesn't work.

I've tried to add remove css for chrome which I've found on google, that also doesn't help

I've added picture so u can see what's going on there. Any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: A screenshot of your CSS/DOM inspector is not a replacement for an actual demo of the problem (I can has jsfiddle?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unwanted spacing between images is generally caused by whitespace (newlines, tabs, spaces, etc.).  There are many ways to deal with this, my personal favorite is to comment out the whitespace so that my formatting stays in tact:

```
<img /><!--
--><img />
```

See more techniques here:  http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

The `border-spacing` property the `div` is inheriting from the table should not be applying at all on image elements because it only works with elements that are behaving as a table.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-spacing

Answer (score 0):

This may have to do with how inline objects are rendered. Try putting the images all on the same line in your markup.

Comment: well, try float: left on the images. You may have to clear: left on the object after the images. If that doesn't work, put your work on JSFiddle